# Is there a guitar effect set up that can emulate the sound of Nashville tuning?

Tags: guitar, tuning, guitar-effects, effects

I really like the sound of Nashville tuning, where you typically replace the EADG (low to high) strings with lower gauage strings to get a really light sparkly sound. Is there a way of emulating this sound without having to re-string my guitar every time I want to do it, using effects pedals?

Comment: Buy a second guitar -- an inexpensive acoustic or electric, and string it and set it up for Nashville tuning. That would be only a little more expensive than investing in a polyphonic pitch-shifter effects pedal, and it would sound much better, too.

Answer (score 5):

The Roland VG pedal boards will change your guitar tuning to whatever your little heart desires.  Joni Mitchell used to use one for her 50+ different guitar tunings. (Source: http://www.jonimitchell.com/library/view.cfm?id=38)

The Roland VGs require a GK hexaphonic pickup that picks up up each string separately.

More info here: http://www.rolandus.com/products/details/849/specs/

Comment: Roland claims the spacing should be fine, at least for the GK-3 pickups, and even provides a mounting plate for Gibson style bridges. What issues did you have? Missed notes or double trigging or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Any Line 6 'Variax' guitar can do this, & you can set up presets you can literally dial in from the guitar itself.

The initial programming needs the guitar to be connected via a specific hardware adapter [supplied as part of the new package] via USB to a computer [Mac or PC] - but the recall, once programmed, is straight from the guitar, so can be used live without a computer.

http://line6.com/guitars/ or find an old one in a second hand shop or eBay...

Answer (score 0):

There are many different makes and models of [polyphonic pitch-shifter effects pedals](http://www.guitarcenter.com/Amplifiers---Effects.gc?src=Pitch+Shift&ipp=25&internal=1&browser=&fsrc=pitch%20shift), but they will shift the pitch of every note you play on *every* string up or down by the same amount. That's not quite the same as Nashville tuning. Furthermore shifting the pitch of the strings by that large of a degree sounds quite artificial.

Go to your local music store and ask what models of polyphonic pitch shifters they sell, and ask to try them out.